# Permutation & Combination - How many 4 digit no's are there whose decimal notation contains not more than two distinct digits?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many 4 digit no's are there whose decimal notation contains not more than two distinct digits?

Comment: Would the downvoter care to share their thoughts on how the question could be improved?

Comment: Leading Zeros not allowed.

Comment: I tried to Solve :

Comment: I tried to Solve : Here is what I got - Number can be aaaa, aaab, aabb. For aaaa - 9C1*4!/4! = 9, For case aaab (not with 0 case) 9C1*8C1*4!/3!= 288, For case aaab (with 0 case,cannot be leading) 9C1*1C1*3!/2! = 27, Now Similarly for case aabb (without zero) - 9C1*8C1*4!/2!^2= 432, with zero 9c1*1c1*3!/2! = 27...  I don't know, if I am doing it correct??? I am getting 9+288+27+432+27....?? Any Idea..

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

- How many $4$-digit numbers use only one digit?
- How many pairs of digits are there?
- If a $4$-digit number uses the digits $a$ and $b$, it must have one $a$ and three $b$’s, two of each, or three $a$’s and one $b$. How many $4$-digit numbers are there in each of those three categories?

Your answer will depend on whether leading zeros are allowed. If they are not allowed, so that you cannot count $0101$, for instance, then you’ll have to split the pairs into those that contain $0$ and those that don’t.

Comment: I tried to Solve : Here is what I got - Number can be aaaa, aaab, aabb. For aaaa - 9C1*4!/4! = 9, For case aaab (not with 0 case) 9C1*8C1*4!/3!= 288, For case aaab (with 0 case,cannot be leading) 9C1*1C1*3!/2! = 27, Now Similarly for case aabb (without zero) - 9C1*8C1*4!/2!^2= 432, with zero 9c1*1c1*3!/2! = 27...  I don't know, if I am doing it correct??? I am getting 9+288+27+432+27....?? Any Idea..

Comment: @Joy: Your $aaaa$ case is correct, as are your two $aaab$ cases. You’ve overcounted $aabb$. Without $0$ there are $9$ ways to choose the first digit, $3$ ways to choose where the other copy of that digit goes, and $8$ ways to choose the other digit, for a total of $9\cdot3\cdot8=216$ numbers. (You counted every one of the twice. For instance, you counted $1221$ once with $a=1$ and once with $a=2$.) With $0$ there are $9$ ways to choose the first digit and $3$ ways to place the other non-zero digit, so your $27$ is right.

Comment: @ Brian - Thanks I figured out the Error. However I get 9+27+288+216+27 = 567, but my Book show 576... :( , which is 9 more.

Comment: @Joy: That may just be a typo in the book. Let me calculate it a different way to check.

Comment: I guess, may be a typo. Thank you for the help :) I'd wait for your final call on this.. :)

Comment: @Joy: The book is right. I didn’t notice that there’s a small error in your count for the $aaab$ case with $0$ case. If $a=0$, there are $9$ possibilities, and if $b=0$, there are $27$, for a total of $36$.

Comment: Perfect, I got it. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @Joy: You’re very welcome.